# Paypal Payment Store Details in Database

Tags: php, paypal

I've created a "Pay Now" paypal button and users can click on it in order to book artists. There are a lot of details they need to fill (artist name, event date, event location etc) and then the last option is to pay for it.

Below is the normal paypal form. I also use some variables from my database (artist's name and surname, budget, id etc)

index.php

```
$url='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'; ?>
$email='my-email@gmail.com';
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action='<?php echo $url; ?>' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='business' value='<?php echo $email; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='<?php echo $name . " " . $surname;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='item_number' value='<?php echo $artist_id;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='amount' value='<?php echo $price;?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='buyer_name' value='<?php echo $b_name; ?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='buyer_phone' value='<?php echo $phone; ?>'>

<input type='hidden' name='no_shipping' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='EUR'>
<input type='hidden' name='handling' value='0'>
<input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://mywebsite.com/fail.php'>
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://mywebsite.com/success.php'>

<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
```

When a user clicks on the button, it goes to paypal site where it shows product details etc. If the payment is successfull, it sends the users to success.php script where it should get the data (cmd, item_name, item_number, amount etc) from the form in index.php

success.php

```
<?php
    $artist_id = $_POST['item_number'];
    $buyer_name = $_POST['buyer_name'];
    $buyer_phone = $_POST['buyer_phone'];
    $item_transaction = $_POST['tx'];
    $item_price = $_POST['amt'];

    echo "Name: $item_no , Surname: $buyer_name, Price: $buyer_phone, ID: $item_transaction  $item_price<br/>";

    //retrieve artist's details
    $getArtist = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artist_id = '$item_no'");
    $details = mysql_fetch_array($getArtist);
    $name = $details['artist_name']; $surname = $details['artist_surname']; $price = $details['artist_budget']; $artist_id = $details['artist_id'];

    //$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO booked_event (pid, buyer_name, buyer_phone, saledate, transactionid) VALUES('$singer_no', '$buyer_name', '$buyer_phone','$event_date','$item_transaction')");
    //if($result){
    //    echo "<p style='text-align: center;'><img src='images/success.png'><br/><br/>";
    //    echo "We will contact you as soon as possible for further details! Please check your email<br/>";
    //    echo "<a href='book.php'><b>Go Back</b></a></p><br/>";

    //}else{
    //    echo "Payment Error";
    //}
        echo "Name: $name , Surname: $surname, Price: $price, ID: $artist_id";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Payment Failed";
    }
?>
```

The problem is that I don't get any details back in order to store them in the database when someone book an artist.
I tried to echo the details and it prints nothing (see echo "Name: $item_no , Surname: $buyer_name, Price: $buyer_phone, ID: $item_transaction  $item_price).

Does anybody know why? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the user has completed the paypal checkout, paypal wont POST back all the data from the form you have there.

Have a look at paypal IPN, it's where once a payment has been completed it will POST a whole bunch of the transaction data to a page on your site of your choice. It includes a 'custom' variable that you could to send your own data back.